# Run Time Error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set Catalogue Mailmerge

Tags: vba, directory, ms-word, mailmerge

I'm trying out the tutorial from macropod for using a directory for a mailmerge, but I keep getting an error which I don't understand.

I've gotten to the last step in the tutorial and I wanted to try out the actual e-mail merge. I created a macro with  the code below in the Catalog/Directory mailmerge main document and saved the document in the same folder as the 'Email Merge Main Document'. But now when I run the macro `RunMerge` I get the error

> Run Time Error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

When I click on debug it highlights the first `.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete` in `Sub EmailMergeTableMaker(DocName As Document)`. This is the first time I've had to do anything with VBA and I have no idea how to solve this.

What does the error mean? I'm guessing the line references a variable which isn't set right, but I just copied the code from the tutorial and I don't know which variable is being referenced.

Edit: this is the link to the tutorial http://www.gmayor.com/Zips/Catalogue%20Mailmerge.zip

```
Sub RunMerge()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Doc1 As Document, Doc2 As Document, Doc3 As Document, StrDoc As String
Set Doc1 = ThisDocument
StrDoc = ThisDocument.Path & "\EmailDataSource.doc"
If Dir(StrDoc) <> "" Then Kill StrDoc
With Doc1.MailMerge
  If .State = wdMainAndDataSource Then
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .Execute
    Set Doc2 = ActiveDocument
  End If
End With
Call EmailMergeTableMaker(Doc2)
With Doc2
  .SaveAs FileName:=StrDoc, AddToRecentFiles:=False, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument
  StrDoc = .FullName
  .Close
End With
Set Doc2 = Nothing
Set Doc3 = Documents.Open(FileName:=Doc1.Path & "\Email Merge Main Document.doc", _
  AddToRecentFiles:=False)
With Doc3.MailMerge
  .MainDocumentType = wdEMail
  .OpenDataSource Name:=StrDoc, ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, _
    LinkToSource:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Connection:="", SQLStatement:="", _
    SQLStatement1:="", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeOther
  If .State = wdMainAndDataSource Then
    '.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .Destination = wdSendToEmail
    .MailAddressFieldName = "Recipient"
    .MailSubject = "Monthly Sales Stats"
    .MailFormat = wdMailFormatPlainText
    .Execute
  End If
End With
Doc3.Close SaveChanges:=False
Set Doc3 = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Sub EmailMergeTableMaker(DocName As Document)
Dim oTbl As Table, i As Integer, j As Integer, oRow As Row, oRng As Range, strTxt As String
With DocName
  .Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete    <---- this line
  Call TableJoiner
  For Each oTbl In .Tables
  j = 2
    With oTbl
      i = .Columns.Count - j
      For Each oRow In .Rows
        Set oRng = oRow.Cells(j).Range
        With oRng
          .MoveEnd Unit:=wdCell, Count:=i
          .Cells.Merge
          strTxt = Replace(.Text, vbCr, vbTab)
          On Error Resume Next
          If Len(strTxt) > 1 Then .Text = Left(strTxt, Len(strTxt) - 2)
        End With
      Next
    End With
  Next
  For Each oTbl In .Tables
    For i = 1 to j
      oTbl.Columns(i).Cells.Merge
    Next
  Next
  With .Tables(1)
    .Rows.Add BeforeRow:=.Rows(1)
    .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Recipient"
    .Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Data"
  End With
  .Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete
  Call TableJoiner
End With
Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub TableJoiner()
Dim oTbl As Table
For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  With oTbl.Range.Next
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then .Delete
  End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please use the [edit] link below the question to add a link to the tutorial?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this tutorial/code, but if `Set doc2 = ActiveDocument` is not picking up a `Document` object, that would be one explanation for the error. For example, if mail merge is not executing (or doesn't finish execution). 1) Comment out the line that turns off screen updating. 2) Use F8 to "step" through the code, line-by-line. When you see the yellow highlight jump from `Execute` to `Set doc2 = ActiveDocument` switch to the Word document(s) and see if there's a mail merge result *and* a main merge document...

Comment: ... When you go back to the VBA Editor, make sure the merge result is the active document. Continue pressing F8 and watch to go through the line you report as having the error. Does the error still occur?

Comment: @CindyMeister I'm out of the office where I have the files saved, but I will try it tomorrow!

Comment: Hi, I thought I wasn't allowed to use external tools for word in the office, but it's allowed. So I've downloaded the tool from doug robbins and now everything is going smooth. Thanks for helping anyway!